# Plugin to compile an index of Java resource files using Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I'm looking for a fast and container-agnostic way of iterating resources files in my .jar. It seems like the most straightforward solution is to simply generate a listing of these files during the compile phase, but strangely, I haven't found a well-supported Maven plugin to do this. I'm kind of surprised that it isn't built right into Maven's resources plugin.

Here's someone that created a simple Maven plugin to do something similar, but do I really have to roll my own?

http://andreashohmann.com/articles/maven-source-file-list-plugin.html